# free cv::Mat without releasing memory

Tags: c++, opencv

I pass the Mat data (not a cv::Mat object) to a function, And make this function the new owner of this data. however, I need a method to free the original object, without freeing the data buffer it points to.

I know that this will happen to cv::Mat that were created from external data, I just need to use this feature for general cv::Mat.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `addref()` method but **you will have a memory leak**.

Actually it is not a good idea to detach data from Mat:

- It was not designed for that;
- You can not guarantee that pointer obtained from general cv::Mat points to the beginning of allocated memory block;
- Most probably you will be unable to release that memory by yourself because cv::Mat may use own memory allocation routines (there are a lot of reasons to do that, for example alignment).
- Even if you find a way to solve all the problems with data pointer, you still can not avoid memory leak for Mat reference counter.

So there are only two ways that Mat is guaranteed to support:

- Provide your pointer on Mat creation;
- Copy data to you buffer.

Any other way can be broken in future versions even if it works in current.

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the Mat with a lambda, and you can use this lambda as a deleter to extend and bound its life to a shared_ptr/unique_ptr.

```
Mat matrix;
...
std::shared_ptr<uchar*> ptr(matrix.ptr(),[matrix](uchar*){});
```

Its useful when you don't want to use the opencv on your public interface, and you can't provide your pointer on Mat creation or don't want to copy data to your buffer.

Comment: This doesnt work on gcc 8. I get a compiler error when i run the code above.

Answer (score 0):

USE **release()**

Ptr

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html

A template class for smart reference-counting pointers

```
template<typename _Tp> class Ptr
{
public:
    // default constructor
    Ptr();
    // constructor that wraps the object pointer
    Ptr(_Tp* _obj);
    // destructor: calls release()
    ~Ptr();
    // copy constructor; increments ptr's reference counter
    Ptr(const Ptr& ptr);
    // assignment operator; decrements own reference counter
    // (with release()) and increments ptr's reference counter
    Ptr& operator = (const Ptr& ptr);
    // increments reference counter
    void addref();
    // decrements reference counter; when it becomes 0,
    // delete_obj() is called
    void release();
    // user-specified custom object deletion operation.
    // by default, "delete obj;" is called
    void delete_obj();
    // returns true if obj == 0;
    bool empty() const;

    // provide access to the object fields and methods
    _Tp* operator -> ();
    const _Tp* operator -> () const;

    // return the underlying object pointer;
    // thanks to the methods, the Ptr<_Tp> can be
    // used instead of _Tp*
    operator _Tp* ();
    operator const _Tp*() const;
protected:
    // the encapsulated object pointer
    _Tp* obj;
    // the associated reference counter
    int* refcount;
};
```

The class Ptr<_Tp> is a template class that wraps pointers of the corresponding type. It is similar to shared_ptr that is a part of Boost library ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm ) and also a part of the C++0x standard.

By using this class you can get the following capabilities:

```
default constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator for an arbitrary C++ class or a C structure. For some objects, like files, windows, mutexes, sockets etc, copy constructor or assignment operator are difficult to define. For some other objects, like complex classifiers in OpenCV, copy constructors are absent and not easy to implement. Finally, some of complex OpenCV and your own data structures may have been written in C. However, copy constructors and default constructors can simplify programming a lot; besides, they are often required (e.g. by STL containers). By wrapping a pointer to such a complex object TObj to Ptr<TObj> you will automatically get all of the necessary constructors and the assignment operator.
all the above-mentioned operations running very fast, regardless of the data size, i.e. as “O(1)” operations. Indeed, while some structures, like std::vector provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator, the operations may take considerable time if the data structures are big. But if the structures are put into Ptr<> , the overhead becomes small and independent of the data size.
automatic destruction, even for C structures. See the example below with FILE* .
heterogeneous collections of objects. The standard STL and most other C++ and OpenCV containers can only store objects of the same type and the same size. The classical solution to store objects of different types in the same container is to store pointers to the base class base_class_t* instead, but when you loose the automatic memory management. Again, by using Ptr<base_class_t>() instead of the raw pointers, you can solve the problem.
```

The class Ptr treats the wrapped object as a black box, the reference counter is allocated and managed separately. The only thing the pointer class needs to know about the object is how to deallocate it. This knowledge is incapsulated in Ptr::delete_obj() method, which is called when the reference counter becomes 0. If the object is a C++ class instance, no additional coding is needed, because the default implementation of this method calls delete obj; . However, if the object is deallocated in a different way, then the specialized method should be created. For example, if you want to wrap FILE , the delete_obj may be implemented as following:

template<> inline void Ptr::delete_obj()
{
    fclose(obj); // no need to clear the pointer afterwards,
                 // it is done externally.
}
...

// now use it:
Ptr f(fopen("myfile.txt", "r"));
if(f.empty())
    throw ...;
fprintf(f, ....);
...
// the file will be closed automatically by the Ptr destructor.

Note : The reference increment/decrement operations are implemented as atomic operations, and therefore it is normally safe to use the classes in multi-threaded applications. The same is true for Mat and other C++ OpenCV classes that operate on the reference counters.

Comment: // decrements reference counter; when it becomes 0,     // delete_obj() is called --- *in the situation i described calling release will delete the object, thus the called function will get freed memory*