# cv::mat constructor, manually assigning data not releasing

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to assign my own raw image data to a `cv::Mat`.  The problem is, when the destructor is called, it doesn't seem to deallocate the data.

```
enum { WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = 480, BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 2, SIZE_BYTES = WIDTH*HEIGHT*BYTES_PER_PIXEL };   

int main()
{
    unsigned char *imageData = new unsigned char[SIZE_BYTES];

    cv::Mat frame444(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC3, imageData);

    frame444.~Mat();  // Doesn't free data.
    delete[] imageData;  // Does free data.

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `frame444.release()` doesn't free the data either.

I'd like to assign my own data to the cv::Mat and have the cv::Mat deallocate it.

Comment: The documentation says *"Once matrix is created, it will be automatically managed by using reference-counting mechanism (unless the matrix header is built on top of user-allocated data, in which case you should handle the data by yourself)."*

Comment: Thank you.  I must've missed that!  Do you know what happens if I create a `cv::Mat` object, and then swap the `cv::Mat` object's data pointer to my own data?

Comment: I think the most sensible way to go is to let `cv::Mat` allocate the data then it logically owns it and can delete it when appropriate. You're mixing ownership of the data which is confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do that, all I have is an `unsigned char*` pointing to where my image is...  I have no choice in this.  Is there any way to get the `cv::Mat` to take control of the data at which the `unsigned char*` is pointing?

Comment: Only by copying the data to a new `cv::Mat`, which is fine if the image is not too big. Alternativley, you could create the `cv::Mat` first, then use its data pointer as the place to store your image. Your question implied that you were using `new` to allocate data first, so I was suggesting using the `cv::Mat` ctor to do this instead.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the ambiguous question.  I'm actually reading 30fps on a microprocessor, and need the data to get the data into the `cv::Mat` as fast as possible.

Comment: Ok, then you can create a `cv::Mat` of the correct size and format beforehand and use its raw data pointer to store your frame. Would this fit your application?

Comment: You might also find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17497458/1601291) interesting.